# While creating keyztore instance getting error as pkcs11 not found

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, pkcs#11, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to create and initialize the IBMPKCS11 provider using config file on java 1.8 64 bit on Linux environment:

While creating the instance of Keystore, getting an error as pkcs11
not  found.

pkcs11.cfg file details are as follows:

```
name = nCipher   
library=/opt/nfast/toolkits/pkcs11/libcknfast.so   
slotListIndex=1    
attributes=compatibility
```

Code:

```
private PrivateKey privateKey;
private static com.ibm.crypto.pkcs11impl.provider.IBMPKCS11Impl 
provider;
provider = new com.ibm.crypto.pkcs11impl.provider.IBMPKCS11Impl(pkcs11.cfg);
Security.addProvider (provider);
privateKey =getPrivateKey(trans.decode(CARDSET_PASSPHRASE).toCharArray(),trans.decode(KEY_ALIAS));

public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(char[] passPhrase, String alias)
throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,         
{
    System.out.println ("Inside getPrivateKey method");
    PrivateKey pk = null;
    try{
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", _provider.getName());    
        ks.load(null, passPhrase);   
        pk= (PrivateKey ) ks.getKey(alias, passPhrase);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pk;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried these steps: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/pkcs11implDocs/init_configfile.html

Comment: Stack trace please. [tag:sunpkcs11] doesn't have anything to do with the IBM PKCS#11 provider.

Comment: In `...IBMPKCS11Impl(pkcs11.cfg)` the `pkcs11.cfg` should be a string literal (in doublequotes) `"pkcs11.cfg"`